# pyspark extract the json value column and post it via rest using requests

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe in PySpark with 1 row 1 column - json

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|json                                                              
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|[{"a":{"b":0,"c":{"50":0.005,"60":0,"100":0},"d":0.01,"e":0,"f":2}}]|
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I need to extract the json value and post it via rest using requests.

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: If you have two question (which you have, splitting JSON-column and posting via REST using request), you should split the question into two seprate questions. This way they are more searchable by others and you can more easily select the best answer for each question. And before asking each question, try to solve then your self and include what you have tried and your efforts in the question. For example, the Google-results for `pyspark extract json` are plenty, have you looked at those and tried? Why didn't that work? e.t.c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import json
spark = (SparkSession.builder.appName("AuthorsAges").getOrCreate())
# Creating the DataFrame
data_df = spark.createDataFrame([["[{\"a\":{\"b\":0,\"c\": 
{\"50\":0.005,\"60\":0,\"100\":0},\"d\":0.01,\"e\":0,\"f\":2}}]"]])
data_df.show(1, False)
extract_text = data_df.collect()[0][0]
extract_json = json.loads(extract_text[1:-1])
# you can access any of the josn fields like this afterwards
print(extract_json['a']['c'])
```